# Error when inserting a record into db: Invalid string or buffer length

Tags: .net, sql, informix

I get the below error when trying to insert a record into an informix db table.  I'm using the .net OdbcCommand control with many different parameters - some dynamic some static.

```
[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid string or buffer length
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I painstakingly found the answer myself.  It's caused by not assigning a value to every dynamic parameter you specify in the query.

Example:

```
string query = "insert into my_table (id, name, phone) values (?, ?, '123-456-7890')";
myOdbcCommandControl.CommandText = query;
myOdbcCommandControl.Parameters["id"].Value = 123456;
//myOdbcCommandControl.Parameters["name"].Value = "john"; // commented out here
myOdbcCommandControl.ExecuteNonQuery(); // errors here because the "name" parameter isn't set
```